# How to list files from directory with wildcard in a Gnome Shell Extension?

Tags: directory, gnome-shell-extensions

I have managed to read the content of a file from the disk with this snippet:

```js
const { Gio } = imports.gi;   

class Indicator extends PanelMenu.Button {                                                                                                                     
 
   _init() {                                                                                                                                                  
        const file = Gio.File.new_for_uri(                                                                                                                     
             'file:.config/wireguard/current_vpn');
        const [, contents, etag] = this._file.load_contents(null);
        const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
        const contentsString = decoder.decode(contents);
    }
}
```

Now I am tryning to list all the `*.conf` files from a directory. But I cannot find a proper way to do that reading the [Gio docs](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/gio20%7E2.66p/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to enumerate the files in the directory and perform your comparison on the file names as you go. There are examples of enumerating files in the [File Operations guide](https://gjs.guide/guides/gio/file-operations.html#navigating-files-and-directories) on gjs.guide:

```js
const {GLib, Gio} = imports.gi;

const directory = Gio.File.new_for_path('.');

const iter = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    directory.enumerate_children_async(
        'standard::*',
        Gio.FileQueryInfoFlags.NOFOLLOW_SYMLINKS,
        GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
        cancellable,
        (file_, result) => {
            try {
                resolve(directory.enumerate_children_finish(result));
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        }
    );
});

while (true) {
    const infos = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        iter.next_files_async(
            10, // max results
            GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
            null,
            (iter_, res) => {
                try {
                    resolve(iter.next_files_finish(res));
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            }
        );
    });

    if (infos.length === 0)
        break;
        
    for (const info of infos)
        log(info.get_name());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The apparently correct answer of andy.hollmes made me sick. This is for a very personnal tool with no sharing purpose, so I am gonna use this trick with bash command (thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47039625/6537892)):

```bash
var files_string = GLib.spawn_command_line_sync(                                                                                                       
    "ls /this/is/a/directory/*.conf")[1].toString().trim();
```

For those who will use the same approach, I have noticed that the absolute path is needed for me. Yet I have read that the extension runs in the user directory...